# ObservableCollection of winform controls

Tags: c#, winforms, observablecollection

I think about create  ObservableCollection of controls (Label and Textbox) and add it to TabPage. If text in this textbox will change by user, text parameter in my collection will change ?

Please help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should take a look at this link where they explain very well the limitations of binding with an ObservableCollection and also give you workarounds for it.

[ObservableCollection<T> in Winforms and possible alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780655/observablecollectiont-in-winforms-and-possible-alternatives)